# Distance in meters between two Spacial Points in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, geospatial

I am trying to query a MySQL database (version 5.7.15) to retrieve all locations that are within 300 meters from some coordinates (40.7542, -73.9961 in my case):

```
SELECT *
FROM location 
WHERE st_distance_sphere(latlng, POINT(40.7542, -73.9961)) <= 300
```

From the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere):

> **ST_Distance_Sphere(g1, g2 [, radius])**
>
> Returns the mimimum spherical distance between two points and/or
>   multipoints on a sphere, in **meters**, or NULL if any geometry argument
>   is NULL or empty.

Unfortunately, the query also returns points that are more than 300 meters away from POINT(40.7542, -73.9961) such as:

- POINT(40.7501, -73.9949)    (~ 470 meters in real life)
- POINT(40.7498, -73.9937)    (~ 530 meters in real life)

Comment: point must be set by this way `POINT(lng, lat)`


`select st_distance_sphere(POINT(-73.9949,40.7501), POINT( -73.9961,40.7542)) `

give us 466.9696023582369 - as expected

Comment: @MituhaSergey but why is the query returning distances greater than 300?

Comment: because you're using incorrect POINT.  

for example   `select st_distance_sphere(POINT(40.7501, -73.9949), POINT(40.7542, -73.9961))`  

will return 183.3146597410617 <= 300.   

just use correct args positions POINT(lng, lat),  lng as first arg, lat - as second

Comment: Hi, I am trying to solve a similar question however my location is set in this format b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\xca\x15\xde\xe5"\xc2_@\x04\xe6!S>\xbeB@'. My guess is that it is set of points creating a polygon however it is point datatype

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Note that in **MySql** the order of coordinates are:

1. `POINT(lng, lat)` - no SRID
2. `ST_GeomFromText('POINT(lng lat)', 4326)` - with SRID

   select st_distance_sphere(POINT(-73.9949,40.7501), POINT( -73.9961,40.7542))

will return 466.9696023582369, as expected, and 466.9696023582369 > 300 of course

Comment: which one is more performant? POINT or Spatial index added to the POINT?

Comment: btw, you can make a stored virtual column with expression like

`st_geomfromgeojson(concat('{ "type": "Point", "coordinates": [',`lng`,' ,',`lat`,']}'))`

and build SPATIAL index with this column

Answer (score 9):

Just to make it clear for future people (like myself):

Mituha Sergey has answered the question in comments on the OP. The problem was that OP was using `POINT(lat, lng)` when in fact MySQL expects `POINT(lng, lat)`.

Not sure about the time OP posted the question, but as of today the official documentation makes it a bit clearer:

> The geometry arguments should consist of points that specify
>   (longitude, latitude) coordinate values:
>
> - Longitude and latitude are the first and second coordinates of the point, respectively.
> - Both coordinates are in degrees.
> - Longitude values must be in the range (-180, 180]. Positive values are east of the prime meridian.
> - Latitude values must be in the range [-90, 90]. Positive values are north of the equator.

From: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere

And if you're getting "invalid arguments" errors it's probably because of that. Try adding `WHERE lat between -90 and 90 AND lng between -180 and 180` just to be on the safe side haha :)

Comment: Thanks to @MacAnthony for fixing the typos ^^