# MYSQL : Selecting from table passing 2 columns value : Incorrect arguments to st_distance_sphere

Tags: mysql, sql

I found this *Stack Overflow* question.

[Distance in meters between two Spacial Points in MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935258/distance-in-meters-between-two-spacial-points-in-mysql-query)

I want to implement it for my use case but I get this error:

> 1210 - #1210 Incorrect arguments to st_distance_sphere.

I have a database table with these columns:

- CompanyObjectId
- CompanyName
- CityName
- Latitude
- Longitude
- CampingLocationType
- PhotoUrl

How can I take the `Latitude` and `Longitude` from each row inside `tbl_cc` table and calculate a result that has distance in meters which is less than or equal 300 meters?

```
SELECT CompanyObjectId, CompanyName, CityName, Latitude, Longitude,
       CampingLocationType, PhotoUrl
FROM tbl_cc
WHERE st_distance_sphere(POINT(13.5145461,43.564368), POINT(Longitude, Latitude)) <= 300
```

I also tried to do this query but got the same error:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT CompanyObjectId, CompanyName, CityName, Latitude, Longitude,
       CampingLocationType, PhotoUrl, (st_distance_sphere(POINT(13.5145461,43.564368), POINT(Longitude, Latitude))) AS MetriDaPosizione
FROM tbl_camper_contact) AS Q WHERE MetriDaPosizione <= 300
```

****UPDATE****

Now where I execute my script in php it generates this query sql for including meters:

```
SELECT CompanyObjectId, CompanyName, CityName, Latitude, Longitude,
                  CampingLocationType, PhotoUrl, st_distance_sphere(point(13.5129324,43.5578855), point(CAST(Longitude AS DECIMAL(18,14)), CAST(Latitude AS DECIMAL(18,14))), 100000) as Metri
                  FROM tbl_camper_contact
            WHERE st_distance_sphere(point(13.5129324,43.5578855), point(CAST(Longitude AS DECIMAL(18,14)), CAST(Latitude AS DECIMAL(18,14))), 100000)
```

In mysql admin it's working but in php I receive this error that make me crazy:

> Mon, 16 Dec 2019 16:14:26 GMT [error] [client 93.36.55.43] -
>   www.testcolan.it - AH01215: PHP Warning: mysqli_query(): (HY000/1210):
>   Incorrect arguments to st_distance_sphere in
>   /web/htdocs/www.testcolan.it/home/campit/rest_api/sql/DBOperations.php
>   on line 759:
>   /web/htdocs/www.testcolan.it/home/campit/rest_api/getListaDoveSostare.php
>   Mon, 16 Dec 2019 16:14:26 GMT [error] [client 93.36.55.43] -
>   www.testcolan.it - AH01215: PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects
>   parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
>   /web/htdocs/www.testcolan.it/home/campit/rest_api/GeneralFunctions.php
>   on line 242:
>   /web/htdocs/www.testcolan.it/home/campit/rest_api/getListaDoveSostare.php

My script php is :

```
public function GetListaDoveSostare($lat, $lng, $kmmin, $ordinamentoData, $localita)
{
  $metri = (intval($kmmin) * 1000);

  $com = new DbConnect();
  $sql = "";


    $sql = "SELECT CompanyObjectId, CompanyName, CityName, Latitude, Longitude,
                  CampingLocationType, PhotoUrl, st_distance_sphere(point(".floatval($lng).",".floatval($lat)."), point(CAST(Longitude AS DECIMAL(18,14)), CAST(Latitude AS DECIMAL(18,14))), $metri) as Metri
                  FROM tbl_camper_contact
            WHERE st_distance_sphere(point(".floatval($lng).",".floatval($lat)."), point(CAST(Longitude AS DECIMAL(18,14)), CAST(Latitude AS DECIMAL(18,14))), $metri)";

  mysqli_set_charset($com->getDb(), 'utf8');
  $result = mysqli_query($com->getDb(), $sql);
  return $result;
}
```

And the return is putted inside function for generating json:

```
 public function GetListaDoveSostare($resultDoveSostare, $lat, $lng)
    {
      $dbOperationsObject = new DBOperations();
      $doveSostare= array();

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultDoveSostare)) {

          $dove_sostare = array(
            "CompanyObjectId" => $row['CompanyObjectId'],
            "CompanyName" => $row['CompanyName'],
            "CityName" => $row['CityName'],
            "Latitude" => $row['Latitude'],
            "Longitude" => $row['Longitude'],
            "CampingLocationType" => ($row['CampingLocationType'] == "Camperplace") ? "Area Sosta" : "Campeggio",
            "PhotoUrl" => $row['PhotoUrl'],
            "MetriDaPosizioneCorrente" =>  $row['Metri']//$metri

          );

          $json= json_encode($dove_sostare);
          $dove_sostare = json_decode($json);
          array_push($doveSostare, $dove_sostare);
      }




      return $doveSostare;

    }
```

Thanks very much for any helps
Cristian

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Oh my god, i forgot the dbms. Mysql.

Comment: updated question pls!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your first query, you are not passing the radius correctly:

```
SELECT CompanyObjectId, CompanyName, CityName, Latitude, Longitude,
       CampingLocationType, PhotoUrl
FROM tbl_cc
WHERE st_distance_sphere(POINT(13.5145461,43.564368), POINT(Longitude, Latitude)) <= 300
```

should be

```
SELECT CompanyObjectId, CompanyName, CityName, Latitude, Longitude,
       CampingLocationType, PhotoUrl
FROM tbl_cc
WHERE st_distance_sphere(POINT(13.5145461,43.564368), POINT(Longitude, Latitude), 300)
```

The error you mention is raised *"if the radius argument is present but not positive".*
See [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html) for further reference

Comment: Ok radius is 300? Is in meters and be considered as <= 300? thanks

Comment: ehm I'm in ancona but not working it must show nearest city by coordinates....

Comment: _"not working"_ means nothing. What is not working? What error do you get? Do you have any place in your table that is 300 **meters** from the cohordinates you provided?

Comment: ehm sorry for short answer...ehm no I've not minus than 300 meters.... if I'm in Ancona (Italy) 300 meters not showing any places entire 300 meters but showing places in Germany...

Comment: then how is your query supposed to return anything?

Comment: my query should restiti given a starting point the points near and within a range of x meters

Comment: Try this link and I'll get this error! http://www.testcolan.it/campit/rest_api/getListaDoveSostare.php?user_id=&ord=crescente&kmmax=100&lat=43.5581473&lng=13.5132756