# MySQL 8 st_distance_sphere gives different values for different SRID

Tags: mysql, spatial-query, srid

When, I run (SRID = 4326)

```
Select st_distance_sphere( ST_GeomFromText( 'point(-51 -23)',4326), ST_GeomFromText('Point(-51.4264 -23.4158)',4326))/1000 as distance;
```

I get

> '55.55951760685804'.

[SRID 4326](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p2Xo.png)

But, when, I run (SRID = 0)

```
Select st_distance_sphere( ST_GeomFromText( 'point(-51 -23)'), ST_GeomFromText( 'Point(-51.4264 -23.4158)'))/1000 as distance;
```

[srid 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF43B.png)

I get `63.5340251950123`, which looks like to be the right distance value.
But, I thought that function do not change its result by changing the SRID of the points. Even worse when its return wrong result when I set the SRID. Someone can help me understand what going on here ? =)
By the way, I am using Mysql 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42183467/14362201). The problem is that when change from SRID 0 to 4326, the lat long order to create the point must change. I did not know that. I think this is really confused and not well documented. Anyway, after change the lat long order in 4326 case, I got the right distance value.